# What is the name for a constant-heading Kalman filter model for vehicle tracking?

Tags: kalman-filters, tracking, unscented-kalman-filter

When applying Kalman filtering to estimate the position of a car, there are several different vehicle dynamics models that you could use.

One of the simplest is "constant velocity" or **CV**, which uses the state
$$
\mathbf x = [x, y, v_x, v_y]
$$

A more sophisticated model is "constant turn rate and velocity" or **CTRV**, which uses the state
$$
\mathbf x = [x, y, \theta, v, \omega]
$$

My coworker has implemented an algorithm that's somewhere in between these two, and I'm wondering what to call it. It uses the state

$$
\mathbf x = [x, y, \theta, v]
$$
I would expect that this model is called "constant heading and velocity" or "constant bearing and velocity" or similar but I haven't found any papers describing it.

**Is there a name in the literature for this model?**

Answer (score 2):

I think the magic acronym is **CHCV**, "constant heading constant velocity". This returns [at least a few results on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22chcv%22+kalman+filter).